# Azure Devops handle special character in yaml

Tags: azure-devops

I have problem with the Azure Devops yaml script, as it doesn't pick up my variable properly to build my ReactJS project. Below is the script, but somehow the build failed at git push, and the username does't get picked up

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '9.8.0'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install --no-save
    npm run build
    git push https://"$(azure.Username)":$(azure.Password)@$(azure.AppName).scm.azurewebsites.net:443/$(azure.AppName).git master
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also `azure.UserName` is your actual variable name? I'm not clear not the git path here! Is this your sample/dummy git?

Comment: my username has special character like $abc, so after npm build, it should push to Azure Webapp using the git push command. Unfortunately, it doesn't pick up the variable and causing error.

the same command works in BitBucket build pipeline

Comment: The YAML documentation doesn't have any reference to the word script, so it would be helpful if you indicated what you mean by "yaml [sic!] script". Were you trying to convey "with the YAML document that is an Azure Devops script" or "with the Azure Devops YAML document that  has a script step" or something else entirely?

Comment: Solved it using single quote in the variable, like '$xxx'

Answer (score 0):

My solution as per the yml file below, and you can set the variable to have "$" sign in it. Another better way is to use the steps in Azure DevOps itself.

```
image: node:9.8.0
clone:
  depth: full
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - npm install --no-save
          - npm run build
          - git push https://$AZURE_LOGIN:$AZURE_PASSWORD@$AZURE_APP_NAME.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/$AZURE_APP_NAME.git master
```

Comment: It looks like you're using _environment variables_ defined by Azure and expanded by the _target shell_  rather than Azure _macros_ that are expanded _up front_ before the shell sees the command, correct?

Answer (score -2):

The correct answer is to wrap the variable in single quotes as such: `'$(myVariable)'`. This prevents the yaml parser from parsing the contents of the variable